# how to send pound sign (#) in query string in oauth url android?

Tags: android, rest, oauth-2.0

I want to pass a password in ouath url which has a pound sign (#) through my android app.

My code for building the string url is

```
String username="example@abc.com";
String password="password#123";
Uri.Builder builder = new Uri.Builder();
    builder.scheme("https")
            .authority("xyz.abc.com")
            .appendPath("app")
            .appendPath("outh")
            .appendPath("token")

            .appendQueryParameter("grant_type", "password")
            .appendQueryParameter("client_id", "someid")
            .appendQueryParameter("client_secret", "some-secret")
            .appendQueryParameter("scope", "read,write,trust")
            .appendQueryParameter("username", username)
            .appendQueryParameter("password", password);
    ;
```

Hitting this url in rest api client I got to know that the pound sign is the issue.

I also got to know that replacing # with %23 makes this working.

But is there any way to convert the password if it contains pound sign?

Comment: [appendQueryParameter already encode](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/net/Uri.java#L1484) ...

Comment: Oh yes, I forgot that!

Comment: @Selvin its not taking #

Comment: this is what `builder.toString()` returns  on my emulator: `xyz.abc.com/app/outh/token?grant_type=password&client_id=someid&client_secret=some-secret&scope=read%2Cwrite%2Ctrust&username=example%40abc.com&password=password%23123` ... as you can see # is replaced ... so problem is not with this code ...